# Squirrel for Windows drops everything in the Publisher Name after a comma

Tags: windows, nuget, nuspec, squirrel.windows

I've discovered that when using [Squirrel for Windows](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) installation framework, the program's Publisher name, as seen in the `Programs and Features` of Windows, is specified by the  `Authors` field of the Package Metadata in the .nuspec file.

However, when I specify a company name that includes a comma, e.g. `Company, Inc.`, the Publisher is displayed as just `Company`, truncating the rest.

Is there a way to specify a company name that includes a comma?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. squirrel sources just get the first author from ZipPackage.Authors out of the nupkg

https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/0d1250aa6f0c25fe22e92add78af327d1277d97d/src/Squirrel/UpdateManager.InstallHelpers.cs#L82

And from what I can tell from the sources when it is creating the manifest from sources like an assembly it just dumps it as a simple comma separated list without attempting to quote or escape commas.  And some simple attempts to quote the string or escape the comma failed as well.

Since I believe the underlying tools that squirrel uses do accept commas in that string (Company Name), it could be made to work by having an encoding for a comma that gets reversed and/or an override property for company name that isn't a list like authors, but that would require a change to squirrel for windows.

You could post an issue on github and see if Paul has a comment and/or help with a pull request for the issue.

Comment: This was fixed in https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/commit/6db88fb23c77dceacec716741adcd8e26048153a